# Create single page with text variable in Android Studio (Kotlin)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, variables, button, text

Is it possible to create a single page in Android Studio (using Kotlin) that displays different text depending on the button you hit on the main screen?

Imagine loading the app, on the home screen there are five buttons, each button you click, displays different text. Instead of creating five pages for the five buttons, can I create the one page and do something with the code to show certain text based on which button I hit?

If it is, how would I go about this and code it?

**Update 1**

This is what I have done, two buttons to navigate to another activity.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn)
    // set on-click listener
    btn.setOnClickListener {

        val intent = Intent(this, Duas::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

        btn1.setOnClickListener {
            textView.text = "newText"

    }

    val btn2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn2)
    // set on-click listener
    btn2.setOnClickListener {

        val intent = Intent(this, Duas::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

        btn2.setOnClickListener {
            textView.text = "newText"
        }

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do that, you make your XML layout which contains the textView and the buttons,
now in your activity class, you need to assign an onClickListener on each button
now inside each one your gonna change the text to whatever you want like so

```
Button1.setOnClickListener { 
        textView.text = "newText"
    }
```

, so whenever you hit the button the text will change to what is assigned to

Comment: Is this code for Kotlin? " .Text = "newText" " doesn't seem to be recognized.

        val btn_click_me = findViewById(R.id.btn_click_me) as Button
            btn_click_me.setOnClickListener {
                textview.Text = "newText" }

Comment: you should use view binding, more about that here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Comment: Sorry to clarify, in my main activity XML, I have five buttons (with Id's and a label). In the main activity kt file, I place the code above. In the code, textView.text = "newText". is textView a general function or do you mean the ID of my text? The "newText" bit.. what if I have the my text as a string? 
      

In my second activity XML, I have a textview with an ID, but the text is blank, in the second activity kt, ive made no changes.

Comment: the Id of your textView, you said you want to change a textView depending on which button you hit, so you use onClickListener on each button, and then inside it, you use the code above to change that textView text to the new text you want.

Comment: This is what I have

''val btn2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn2)
        // set on-click listener
        btn2.setOnClickListener {

            val intent = Intent(this, Duas::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

            btn2.setOnClickListener {
                textView.text = "newText"
            }''

Comment: I've updated the Q with the code I have